# Why can the return keyword be omitted in some Python functions?

Tags: python, function

I am new to Python and want to understand why there is no use of `return` in the following code, and still it is working perfectly fine.

```py
def printCount(num):
    for i in range(2, num +1):
        print(i)
printCount(10)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Return statement is needed only if you want your function to return a value which can be used later. Here you just want to print inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python `return` stops the function, and sends the returned value back. For example:

```py
def printCount(num):
    for i in range(2, num +1):
        return(i) #THIS IS USING RETURN
printCount(10)

count = printCount(5)
```

In this code, on the first iteration in the for loop, it would return i, which would be 2. This would stop the function and set the variable `count` to the returned value, which is 2. The function wouldn't do anything else.

In your code, I pressume that return is not used because the desired output is:
2
3
4
5...

If you used return, the code would send back `2` at the beginning and that would be it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the `return` statement in your function definition, the implicit statement

```
return None
```

is appended to the function body.

It means that your code

```
def printCount(num):
    for i in range(2, num +1):
        print(i)
printCount(10)
```

is fully equivalent to the code

```
def printCount(num):
    for i in range(2, num +1):
        print(i)
    return None
printCount(10)
```